# What's the cmd/PowerShell equivalent of back tick on Bash?

Tags: bash, powershell, cmd

Redirecting command output:

For example:

```
echo "Foo `./print_5_As.rb`"
```

would echo "Foo AAAAA"

Comment: You are asking two questions: one for CMD, and one for PowerShell.

Comment: For cmd.exe, there's a nice alternative described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks

Answer (score 167):

The PowerShell syntax is based on the POSIX ksh syntax
(and interestingly *not* on any of Microsoft's languages
like CMD.EXE, VBScript or Visual Basic for Applications),
so many things work pretty much the same as in Bash. In
your case, command substitution is done with

```
echo "Foo $(./print_5_As.rb)"
```

in both PowerShell and Bash.

Bash still supports the ancient way (backticks), but
PowerShell cleaned up the syntax and removed redundant
constructs such as the two different command substitution
syntaxes. This frees up the backtick for a *different*
use in PowerShell: in POSIX ksh, the backslash is used as
escape character, but that would be *very* painful in
PowerShell because the backslash is the traditional path
component separator in Windows. So, PowerShell uses the
(now unused) backtick for escaping.

Comment: It's great reading answers like this where you get to learn how and why things are. Thanks! (I'd do +10 if I could.)

Answer (score 29):

In PowerShell, you use $( ) to evaluate subexpressions...

For example:

```
PS C:\> "Foo $(./print_5_As.rb)"
Foo AAAAA
```

Answer (score 26):

In CMD.EXE there is no direct equivalent. But you can use the FOR command to achieve what you want.

Do something like the following:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %x IN (`./print_5_As.rb`) DO @echo Foo %x
```

or

```
FOR /F %x IN ('"./print_5_As.rb"') DO @echo Foo %x
```

You might need to set delimiter to something else than the default, depending on how the output looks and how you want to use it. More details available in the FOR documentation at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx

Comment: Cumbersome, unlike it's uber-elegant bash equivalent:  `for x in \`./print_5_As.rb\`; do echo %x; done`

Comment: @jordanpg, you seem to miss the point that FOR in this case is not used for looping. The bash equivalent would still be as in the original post, without any for loop.

Comment: Only the first "word" of the output of print_5_As.rb is echoed if the output contains spaces.