# Batch equivalent of Bash backticks

Tags: bash, batch-file, backticks

When working with Bash, I can put the output of one command into another command like so:

```
my_command `echo Test`
```

would be the same thing as

```
my_command Test
```

(Obviously, this is just a non-practical example.)

I'm just wondering if you can do the same thing in Batch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the result of a command in a variable in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows)

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/434038/6064933

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can do it by redirecting the output to a file first.  For example:

```
echo zz > bla.txt
set /p VV=<bla.txt
echo %VV%
```

Comment: It requires you to find a place where you have write access to store the temporary file; you have to clean up after yourself; this very example only enables you to read the very first line of input. For all practical purposes the `for /f` variant is a much better one.

Comment: @grawity - along with `%random%`

Comment: @joey It does read each line, but how to concatenate to a command line argument in a *single* command.

Comment: how does it handle newline(s)?

Answer (score 117):

You can get a similar functionality using cmd.exe scripts with the `for /f` command:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`echo Test`) do my_command %%a
```

Yeah, it's kinda non-obvious (to say the least), but it's what's there.

See `for /?` for the gory details.

Sidenote: I thought that to use "`echo`" inside the backticks in a "`for /f`" command would need to be done using "`cmd.exe /c echo Test`" since `echo` is an internal command to `cmd.exe`, but it works in the more natural way.  Windows batch scripts always surprise me somehow (but not usually in a good way).

Comment: Well, everything in that line is executed by `cmd` anyway; why would you need to spawn a subshell for commands that are perfectly legal there already?

Comment: @Johannes: I seem to remember situations where trying to execute internal commands had to be done by specifying `cmd.exe` or `command.com` (this might be some dark memory from MS-DOS days), but I don't recall the details - I might even be entirely mistaken. I was mildly surprised (but not greatly surprised) when `echo` worked in this case without spawning `cmd.exe`.  Maybe I'm getting confused by times I had to configure other programs to execute internal commands.  I should probably just get rid of the note.

Comment: You usually have to do this when executing shell-builtins from external programs that don't automatically spawn a shell. I.e. C's `system()` was fine, iirc, since it starts a shell in any case but .NET's `Process.Start` needs to explicitly invoke the shell. Something like that, iirc. In any case, I consider this to be the better answer than the accepted one :-)

Comment: The options to `for` don't hurt but confuse the issue.  What about this: `for /f %%a in ('"echo Test"') do my_command %%a`

Comment: Use a single % instead of %% when executing the same on the command line, rather than in a batch script.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work well with piping, for example the ">" operator. But otherwise this is awesome. Unless this was just a % vs %% issue i had.

Comment: @Evan: `tokens=*` is important. Otherwise, if the result of the command includes spaces, only the first word is output. Run this at the prompt: `for /f %a in ('"echo foo bar"') do echo "%a"`. It will print `"foo"`.

Comment: Also worth noting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841622#20841821) if trying to use pipe symbols etc. in the command.

Comment: Node that you can also do the inverse: `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (\`cmd\`)`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, your intuition about needing a subshell is close to correct. A `FOR /f` loop is designed to run a child process and read standard output from a pipe. For an internal command such as `ECHO`, in this case CMD implicitly executes it via `cmd.exe /c`. You can confirm this by attaching a debugger.

Comment: ``$ for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`echo Test`) do dir %%a`` returns `%%a was unexpected at this time`.
How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 36):

Read the documentation for the "for" command: `for /?`

Sadly I'm not logged in to Windows to check it myself, but I think something like this can approximate what you want:

```
for /F %i in ('echo Test') do my_command %i
```

Comment: In case someone else stumbles on this, when the command is executed from a batch file (*.bat), both %i variables need to be double percent sign: %%i.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm screwing up the syntax of the standard `for /f` method, but when I put a very complex command involving && and | within the backticks in the limit of the `for /f`, it causes problems.  A slight modification from the usual is possible to handle an arbitrary complexity command:

```
SET VV=some_command -many -arguments && another_command -requiring -the-other -command | handling_of_output | more_handling
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`%VV%`) do mycommand %%a
```

By putting your full and complex command in a variable first, then putting a reference to the variable in the limit rather than putting the complex command directly into the limit of the for loop, you can avoid syntax interpretation issues.  Currently if I copy the exact command I have set to the `VV` variable in the example above into where it's used, `%VV%`, it causes syntax errors.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I found that you can do piping directly within the for command if you escape it with a carat (^): for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (\`command ^| command\`) do command %%a

Comment: @Heptite Card escaping didn't work for me, but surrounding command line with double quotes did.

Comment: @Heptite In my case I didn't know the series of commands I was going to need to run beforehand, they were extracted out of a file in one case, and passed in in another.  With the escaping you need to know how many times to escape the command based on how many interpreters it's going to run through, and in my use cases that wasn't a consistent number of interpreters.

Answer (score 2):

You could always run [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) inside Windows. I do it all the time with [MSYS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#Components) (much more efficient than [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)).

Comment: Unfortunately MSYS is barely maintained now, to get an up-to-date bash you need to install it separately

Comment: BusyBox is even smaller (~432KB). Not a full Bash though, just Ash. Get the inofficial Windows port here: http://frippery.org/busybox