# equivalent of unix `` (backticks) in DOS?

Tags: unix, command-line, dos, backticks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch equivalent of Bash backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks)

In unix we use `` for command output substitution.

e.g.

```
export a=`pwd`
```

Is there any equivalent for this (``) in DOS command prompt?

Answer (score 12):

Unix:

```
export var1=`pwd`
```

DOS:

```
FOR /F %a IN ('pwd') DO SET var1=%a
```