# Windows: How to read command-line options from external file?

Tags: java, windows, command-line

javac.exe provides a mechanism to [read arguments from external files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#commandlineargfile) (`@argfile`). java.exe does not provide this mechanism.

Is there a generic mechanism for getting Windows to read some of the command-line options from an external file (and others from the normal command-line) in order to emulate the same behavior for `java.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a one-liner, but the following should do the trick:

```
SET /P ARGS=<foo.txt
java -someArgs %ARGS% -moreArgs
```

See also [Batch equivalent of Bash backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks).