# Error: "|" was unexpected at this time batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I run this script, I receive

> | was unexpected at this time.

This is code:

```
@ECHO Off

REM Mapeo de unidad U, path de usuario

    net use u: \\server\usuarios\%username%
pause
REM  ***** Description group ****

for /f %%i in ('net user %username% /domain | find /i /c Group') do set RESULT=%%i

echo %RESULT%

pause
```

In `for` sentence, `i` use `"` and `'`, but I still got error.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The condition inside the `for` must be parsed by the batch parser before it can pass it to the IN() clause as an executable command and since the pipe is a special character in DOS, you need to use escape character(^) before pipe to preserve it during the initial batch parsing, as shown below:

```
for /f %%i in ('net user %username% /domain ^| find /i /c Group') do set RESULT=%%i
```

Comment: When the `for` command line is readed, the parser finds a pipe character that is not enclosed inside a quoted string. In this case, parser interprets there is a pipe creation request, and `for` command line is split in two to create the indicated pipe. But this is not what is needed in this case, pipe is not part of the `for` command. Pipe is in the command that will generate the output that is going to be readed by the `for /f` command. And to signal that to the parser, pipe character is escaped. That way, the parser does not try to split the `for` command line at the pipe character.

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the pipe char inside `for` command. It should be `^|`