# Moving Files up one Directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking to make a batch script that will move all images in sub subfolders down to the layer above the batch script.  For Example:

comics\move.bat

comics\series 000\series 000 blah\01.jpg,02.jpg, etc.

comics\series 001\series 001 blah\series blah\01.jpg,02.jpg, etc.

into

comics\series 000\01.jpg,02.jpg, etc.

comics\series 001\01.jpg,02.jpg, etc.

I've tried several variations of 
for /r %%i in (*.jpg) do move "%%~fi" "%%~pi*.jpg"

But it won't do anything. One way I had it would move all images into the same folder as I was running the script from but that's the closest I've gotten. A clean up of the now empty folders would be nice too!

Comment: Perhaps one `for` loop to stop into each subfolder and another `for/r` within to move the files below, there?

Comment: You state "up one directory" yet your second example is up 2. please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should move the images in each branch into the first level folder, but doesn't deal with filename collisions.

Test it on a folder of copies of your files.

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    pushd "%%a"
        for /r %%b in (*.jpg) do move "%%b" . 
    popd
)
pause
for /L %%a in (1,1,5) do for /d /r %%b in (*) do rd "%%b" 2>nul
```

The last line should remove only empty folders up to 5 levels deep, if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .bat file with following content on the root folder and double click it.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%d in (`dir /s /b /o:n /ad`) do (
  cd "%%d"
  for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in (`dir /b /o:n /a-d`) do (
    move /y "%%f" ..
  )
)
pause
```

To explain the code, the outer loop iterates directories recursively and cd into it. The inner loop iterates all files inside the directory and move it one up above. `/y` flag on move is to suppress prompting. Use `dir /?` for explanation of all the dir flags. As for the `for` part I took it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2768660/179630

Comment: This is going to shuffle all files up a folder level, rather than move all files into one folder, right?  I think the title is misleading because the question and example asks to move all files in a branch into one folder.

Comment: Now the question has been edited it looks very different :). I'll fix my answer some time soon.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
move comics\series 000\series 000 blah\*.jpg comics\series 000
```