# Command line: how to use the content of a text file as an input argument to a program in windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

In one directory I have two files:

'program.exe' and 'content.in'

How do I start 'program.exe' with the content of 'content.in' as an argument from the command-line in windows ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'program.exe' accepts input from standard in you would

```
program.exe < content.in
```

If it doesn't then you are dependent on the program processing files through command arguments, potentially like

program.exe content.in

or

program.exe -i content.in

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this by putting the contents of the file into a variable, borrowing the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2768658/391161).

```
set /p VV=<content.in
program.exe %VV%
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
for /F "tokens=*" %i in ('content.in') do program.exe %i
```

(In a batch file, replace `%i` with `%%i`.)

Note that if `content.in` contains more than one line of text, `program.exe` will be run multiple times, once for each line.