# classpath file from maven dependency plugin for java command line

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, command-line

I want to get the `maven dependency` of a project and use it as a `classpath` for my command line project (windows batch).

This is what I did as per the [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) in my `batch` file.

```
call mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=test.txt
java -cp `cat test.txt` com.hqly.main.Hqly
```

But the `cat` command is not getting executed and the `classpath` is not getting set correctly. Its not seeing my `main` class.
Am getting the below error while trying to `execute`

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:build-classpath (default-cli) @ hqly ---
[INFO] Skipped writing classpath file 'C:\Users\chandrans1\Desktop\GitHub\hqly\test.txt'.  No changes found.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.926s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 16 15:44:39 BST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/txt`
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.txt`
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: test.txt`.  Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Linux, Windows does not use back-ticks as a way of passing the result of a command as a program argument.

You can check this question for some ideas on how to work around this limitation in Windows: [Batch equivalent of Bash backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks). Something like this following should work:

```
for /f %%i in (test.txt) do set HSQLY_CLASSPATH=%%i
echo Classpath is "%HSQLY_CLASSPATH%" 
java -cp %HSQLY_CLASSPATH% com.hqly.main.Hqly
```

Comment: Thanks @Duncan, edited your answer which worked for me.

Comment: @SajanChandran Ah yes, I left `cat` in there which won't really help on Windows :-)