# I want to write a batch file that internally calls python script and I want python script to return some value to the batch file. how can I do that?

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm calling python script as follows:
      start python file.py
How can I get the output in a variable?

Comment: @MA1 The question says "batch file", so I would assume it's talking about Windows CMD.exe batch files. That question is about bash.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `start` complicates matters. It starts a program running and doesn't wait for it to finish. You probably don't want to use `start` if you also want to wait for the program to finish and use its output.

Since other programs can't "reach into" your batch process and change its variables, you need to use some mechanism to output the information from the program and a mechanism to read that information and turn it into variables in the batch file.

If your output mechanism is just for the program to print to standard output (note: you should not use `start` in this case, since it will send standard output to a new window instead), you can redirect it to a file and then read it into a variable. Batch files don't make this easy, but it is possible: [Batch equivalent of Bash backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks)

Alternatively, if you can change the Python program, you can also take a slightly simpler approach - you can have the Python script write out a batch file directly, then have the first batch file call that one. E.g.:

```
python script.py
call generated.bat
echo %MYVAR%
```

Where the Python script creates a file `generated.bat`:

```
set MYVAR=This is an example
```

Comment: Yep.. worked for me..
start was the problem.