# Similar functionality to `...` in linux shell in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell

In Linux / Unix shells there is this syntax where you can execute a command and in this command are other commands which are executed first and then substituted so something like this:

```
gcc main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Here the `pkg-.....` gets executed first and then substituted with its output and then the overall command is executed

Is there some similar functionality in Windows PowerShell (and if possible cmd too as I work with both sometimes)

All that I know is that in PowerShell you can write something like this:

```
gcc main.c (pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)
```

But the problem with this is that the output of the secondary command is passed like a single continuous string so something like this "-mms-bitfields ....." and gcc doesn't recognize it as separate commands.

Comment: Why is this question tagged c?

Comment: Well, because this is a question any c programmer on windows would like to know at least from my point of view. I could remove it if you want.

Comment: From what I know it's really hard to use the PowerShell or any windows shell with the same features that *nix shells have, mainly because there are a lot of programs in the *nix world that do very nice things to make life easier, when I thy to use windows shell I feel like my fingers are heavy, It's my opinion though and might very will be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [-split operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx):

```
gcc main.c ((pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) -split " ")
```

Or possibly

```
gcc main.c ((pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) -split " +")
```

to avoid empty arguments in case there are multiple spaces between arguments in the output (although I don't think `pkg-config` does that).

The -split operator does precisely what it says on the tin: It splits what it is given at occurrences of the given pattern. That is to say,

```
PS C:\> "foo bar baz" -split " "
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. is there anything similar for CMD.

Comment: Not off the top of my head, I'm afraid. I try not to do that sort of thing in cmd. Happily, with the death of Windows XP, you can rely on the presence of Powershell.

Comment: ok, I think I know what you mean. anyway thanks again for your help.

Comment: There's a workaround for cmd in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks); it does give me an extra empty argument at the end if the output ends with a newline, though.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but maybe I should really concern moving completely to PowerShell as you suggested.