# Get command result as define in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I want to set my some define in code to result from some command (for example get current revision number). What is the easiest way to achieve this ?
I think about generate in prebuild step some header file, but mayby there is simpler solution.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a better way than a generated header file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the build process command lines, you might be able to integrate this into VS command line via [`/D`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx) parameter. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks) for discussion on how output from some command can be integrated into another command.