# Can't run $(git rev-parse --short HEAD) in package.json on Virtualbox

Tags: node.js, git, docker, npm

I have a package.json that contains this script:

```
"scripts": {
    "docker-build": "docker build -t url.com/repository:$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) ."
}
```

I use this to create automatic tags from Git on mye Docker-images. This works on Mac, but not on a Windows-machine running Docker Quickstart Terminal.

Is it possible to run the `$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)` command from NPM-script on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, even though you might have a bash environment on your windows system, the npm `scripts` will think they have to run in a Windows shell.  (This lack of cross-platform portability is one of the big limitations of npm scripts.)

If having platform-specific scripts is ok, then you could refer to this question for how to do something similar in a windows shell: [Batch equivalent of Bash backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks)

Comment: Your comment sent me in the right direction. My solution was to move the entire docker-build-command into its own file, *docker-build.sh*, and then run this file from package.json. *bash .docker/docker-build.sh*