# How to evaluate expression result with batch commands

Tags: batch-file, docker, aws-ecr

In the batch file I wrote, I want to login to aws ecr to pull down docker images. To login, I need to run

```
aws ecr get-login --region=xxx
```

which returns

```
docker login {login-credential}
```

The actual commands to login. So I need to evaluate the result of `aws ecr get-login --region=xxx`.

In shell script, I can just put the expression inside `${ ... }`, but how do I do this in batch file?

---

ps. I tried `call aws ecr get-login --region=xxx`, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: How is this related to Windows [tag:batch-file]s?

Comment: Perhaps use stdin i.e. `aws ecr get-login --region=xxx < reply.txt` which reads answers from the file *reply.txt*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch equivalent of Bash backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks)

Comment: thumbs up, thanks guys! I think Simone's answer might be what I'm looking for.