# set CMD output to variable

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

This is what I have:

```
> set email=echo abc@xyz.com
> echo %email%
```

the above snippet echoes `echo abc@xyz.com`. I want it to print `abc@xyz.com` instead.

I tried `echo abc@xyz.com | set email` as well. same result.

How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch equivalent of Bash backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks)

Comment: Any reason to not just `set "email=abc@xyz.com"`?

Answer (score 0):

You could let cmd eval it:

```
@ECHO OFF
set email=echo abc@xyz.com
%email%
```

I use this on our Windows 10, 2016 and 2019 regulary. I don't know if it works for older versions though.