# heroku isn't accepting command "config:get"

Tags: heroku, migration

I keep trying to run the command

```
env SSL=true DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL) npm run migrate
```

in git bash to migrate to my heroku database.

For some reason I keep on getting the error `env: ‘config:get’: No such file or directory` as a result, but I need to have SSL be true in order to avoid a "no pg_hba.conf entry" error.

Comment: What operating system are you using? I suspect you really just want to do `SSL=true DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL) npm run migrate`, omitting `env`.

Comment: Windows 10. I tried omitting env, but that caused "SSL" to become unrecognizable.

Comment: Ah, on Windows you'll need to use completely different syntax. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Oh, I misread earlier. You're trying to run this via Git bash... what does 'that caused "SSL" to become unrecognizable' mean? I think the last part of my answer will work for you, anyway.

Comment: I'm quite certain that you shouldn't be running `env` here. If you can [edit] your question to expand on what you mean by 'that caused "SSL" to become unrecognizable' we may still be able to help you. Alternatively, you should be able to simply run your migration on Heroku as I suggested at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're trying to run appears to be designed for Linux-y shells, not Windows-y shells.

On PowerShell, try this:

```
PS C:\> $env:SSL = 'true'
PS C:\> $env:DATABASE_URL = heroku config:get DATABASE_URL
PS C:\> npm run migrate
```

If you're using cmd.exe, [setting a variable from command output is pretty horrible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2768608/354577). I'd probably just use PowerShell or manually copy the database string:

```
C:\> set SSL=true
C:\> heroku config:get DATABASE_URL
<copy database URL>
C:\> set DATABASE_URL <paste database URL>
C:\> npm run migrate
```

Better yet, consider [running your migration right from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run):

```
heroku run npm run migrate
```