# What is the format of regular expressions in gitk?

Tags: regex, git, tcl, gitk

I'm trying to use the find/"adding/removing string"/regular expression option in gitk.  The syntaxes I have tried don't work, and I can find no docs that describe the syntax of the regular expressions it accepts.

I'm trying to match both `Modem_Wakup` and `Modem_UnWakeup`.  Neither `Modem_(Un)?Wakeup` nor
`Modem_\(Un\)?Wakeup`, nor `Modem_\(Un\)\?Wakeup`, nor any other obvious ones work.  I can find the strings individually, so I know there should be matches.

So what syntax does it use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature should be based on the [pickaxe grep system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-in-the-git-history/2928721#2928721), based on [POSIX regexp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).

But [this thread](http://lists-archives.org/git/737665-gitk-find-commit-adding-removing-string-possible-pickaxe-bug.html) reports some bug around this from gitk:

> I presented the issue to #git, and it was suggested that it is probably a pickaxe bug in that **it doesn't display changes in merge commits if they add strings that neither of their parents has**.

This may not be your exact case though, simply an illustration that the feature isn't fully available yet.