# Regexp search as case insensitive in gitk

Tags: git, gitk

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084528/what-is-the-format-of-regular-expressions-in-gitk) mentioned regexp in gitk is based on pickaxe grep system. How could do search as case insensitive based on this? I saw there is an `-i` [option](https://github.com/git/git/commit/accccde483c3cfd55ef55037e8802ca0baaee5a1) for git, but it appears cannot pass any extra option in the search box in gitk.