# How to search history of a repo?

Tags: git, mercurial

Have a repo with lots of commits. I know the name of the file, and *the thing* (a string, some coefficients to be precise) I am looking for, but I don't know what commit it's in. It's no longer at the current one, that's for sure, nor is it in the few previous ones.

***How can I search *time-wise*, so to speak, for a certain *thing* within a specified file (or within the whole repo, I don't care), so it goes through all the commits until he finds it?***

Interested in both mercurial & git. Use both currently, and I don't really know whether this is possible in either one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mercurial has the [`grep`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/grep) command.  From the documentation:

> hg grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
>
> search for a pattern in specified files and revisions
>
> ```
> Search revisions of files for a regular expression.
>
> This command behaves differently than Unix grep. It only accepts
> Python/Perl regexps. It searches repository history, not the working
> directory. It always prints the revision number in which a match appears.
>
> By default, grep only prints output for the first revision of a file in
> which it finds a match. To get it to print every revision that contains a
> change in match status ("-" for a match that becomes a non-match, or "+"
> for a non-match that becomes a match), use the --all flag.
> ```

For Git, this related question seems relevant:

[How to grep (search) committed code in the git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-in-the-git-history)

Answer (score 2):

Git has the grep command as well.

```
git grep regex $(git rev-list --all) file
```

See [How to grep (search) committed code in the git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-in-the-git-history) for more ways to search.

Answer (score 1):

With git you can use a pickaxe search. There's two interesting flags to `git log`:

```
-S<string>
    Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of <string>.
    Note that this is different than the string simply appearing in diff
    output; see the pickaxe entry in gitdiffcore(7) for more details.
```

This lets you find the commits that add or remove a given string.

```
-G<regex>
    Look for differences whose added or removed line matches the given
    <regex>.
```

This lets you find commits where an added or removed line matches the regular expression.

You can run this on a specific file by filtering the output of `git log` with `-- filename`, e.g. `git log -Scoeff -- myfile.c`

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial (fresh) have [revsets](http://selenic.com/hg/help/revsets), which will allow to find anything and more easy than using grep (in common)