# How can I search a word in Git repo over the whole history?

Tags: git

Suppose I remember that I saved a word `"XYZword"` to some file in a repo but it got killed and I can only remember the initial part `"XYZ"` but nothing about the time or file. How can I grep this `"XYZ"` over the whole history?

Comment: Related: *[Grep all commits in a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206886/)* and *[How to grep (search through) committed code in the Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-through-committed-code-in-the-git-history)*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To search the full history of the current branch and get the line numbers:

```
git grep -n "XYZ" $(git rev-list --all)
```

Comment: I just get "Argument list too long" from this

Comment: I found (through experience) that git grep appears to only look with the current working directory. I needed to run this command from my root directory for it to find files in other subdirectories containing the target text.

Answer (score 5):

`git log -S[SOME_WORD_OR_REGEX]` will search your history for any changes that contain the word or regex you supplied. For more information, check out the *pickaxe* entry in *gitdiffcore(7)*.

Comment: More efficient than the `git rev-list --all` solution, as it would eat only one CPU. Just in case we need the other ones for something else.