# Git search all diffs

Tags: git, search, grep, diff

I'm trying to search for changes in my git history relating to a very specific variable name.

I've tried doing this:

```
git diff HEAD~25000 | grep -in mydistinctvariablename
```

The results don't tell me which commit the result lines are from and it takes quite a bit of time (about 5-7 minutes).

Does anyone have a better solution, time and results wise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grep (search) the git history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-the-git-history)

Comment: Hmm none of those commands tell me which revision the search result came from, only the file that the change happened in

Comment: Does for me, it's the SHA before the filename in the results. I used the first command in the first answer. The [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2928721/211563) there is probably more what you're looking for though, and that also gives the SHA (provided your log format shows it).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[git log](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) is generally the command to use when examining commit history. `git log --grep` can be used to search for regular expressions in the commit message.

What you are after is `git log -S` which searches the commit content simply or `git log -G` which searches it with a regular expression:

> `-S<string>`
> Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of `<string>`. Note that this is different than the string simply appearing in diff output; see the pickaxe entry in gitdiffcore(7) for more details.

So, for instance, in the `msysGit` repository I can find the commit that introduced Tcl 8.5.8 using either:

```
C:\src\msysgit\src>git log --oneline --grep "8\.5\.8"
d938476 Make `NO_SFX=1 portable-release.sh` work
ef1dc94 Update tk to version 8.5.8
a910049 Update tcl to version 8.5.8
a702d7f tcltk: update to 8.5.8 and exclude release.sh from the cleanup list
```

which just looked for 8.5.8 in the commit messages or as you want to do looking at a string that only occurred in the committed diff:

```
C:\src\msysgit\src>git log --oneline -S"version=8.5.8"
7be8622 tcltk: update release.sh script for tcl/tk 8.5.9
a702d7f tcltk: update to 8.5.8 and exclude release.sh from the cleanup list
```

The range limiting you have in your sample can still be used here to limit the commits to be examined. Read though the git log manual carefully to get a good idea of all the things it can do.

Note that `-S` just looks for simple string differences - if you really want to search the content using a regular expression similar to you example then you should use the `-G` option instead of `-S` but this will be significantly slower.

Comment: If I may, in the first snippet, the line `d938476 Make \`NO_SFX=1 portable-release.sh\` work` is confusing, as is hints that the first snippet is what the second is (in other words, I think it would be clearer if that line was removed from the sample output...)