# Search for historic code in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

I would like to search for a piece of deleted code in TFS. I just know a class name that was deleted a while ago and I'd like to check how it used to work. I don't know when it was deleted.

Is there a way to search for a code piece that was once part of the project?

Comment: Do you remember the file name of the code?

Comment: No, I just remember the code piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class name you deleted is `abc`, you can use the following git command to find the commit where you add and delete the class:

```
git log -Sabc
```

[image]

To see more options, please refer these questions: [Find deleted content in a Git repository; I only know surrounding context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828806/find-deleted-content-in-a-git-repository-i-only-know-surrounding-context#:%7E:text=If%20you%20can%20remember%20the%20function%20name%2C%20or,deletion%29%2C%20so%20you%20will%20certainly%20find%20your%20code.) and [Git history - find lost line by keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839253/git-history-find-lost-line-by-keyword/2839319#2839319)

Comment: Thanks, the find lost line link was very useful in my particular case.