# Way to search source in Gitolite repos?

Tags: git, gitolite

There are a bunch of git projects in a couple of Gitolite repositories. Is there a way to search the source contained in a Gitolite repo for a keyword?

I'd like to be able to search all the git projects for keywords without having to manually clone every one of them locally first. For those projects that are built by Jenkins, the source is exposed in directories that can be searched. But not all of them are currently built in this way.

Answer (score 1):

A former coworker that I emailed knew a way to do this. On the machine where the repo is stored, cd into the repository directory that contains the projects. Inside an individual project's .git dir, you can use "git grep" on HEAD or a branch. To search across all dirs, use a loop from the dir of project dirs:

```
for x in *; do
  cd $x
  git grep "MyString" HEAD
  cd ..
done
```

An example with more options, including the name of the project that contains each match:

```
for x in *; do
  cd $x
  git grep -i "mystring" HEAD -- '*.java' | sed "s|\(.*\)|$x-->\1|"
  cd ..
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Gitolite is just an [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html), which intercepts:

- git command
- user id

, and decides if the git command is allowed to proceed.

It has nothing to do with the search feature itself.

You need another app to implement the search itself in your git repo, like **[Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)**.
See "[Searching a git repository with ElasticSearch](http://dev.af83.com/2011/11/15/searching-a-git-repository-with-elasticsearch.html)".

You can then couple it with gitolite (in order to allow the search or to filter the search results, depending on gitolite access rules).

Comment: Thanks for the search service suggestion, but it looks like there is a way to search the source from the machine that has the repo (see my answer).

Comment: @CincinnatiJoe true, but it is purely a git search, and has nothing to do with Gitolite. My answer address the Gitolite side of your question. For a pure git search, I would recommend `git grep` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history), and *not* grepping the `.git`.

Comment: I see how git grep is useful for searching one project that you've cloned. But my question was how to search all projects in a repo without having to first clone all of them locally. The way I just found to do that is to login to the repo machine and use git grep in a loop against each project in the repo. If there's a different/better way that doesn't involve getting on the repo machine, I'd love to hear it (and doesn't involve installing a separate service as this may not be needed often).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always create a "grep" command.  After all, if you can run 'symbolic-ref', what's grep?

One issue will be that gitolite's restrictions on allowed characters would put a crimp in arbitrary regexes being supplied.  (If someone really, *really* wants this -- and by that I mean they ask on the mailing list and at least a couple more people chime in saying "yes we want it!"), I could create a way to allow some programs to have unrestricted arguments.  That code is just waiting to be pulled off from the 'git-annex' branch, but getting no love for testing, so far).

You could even make it search multiple projects.  For example, to make it search *all* the projects the user has read access to, you could start with this:

```
gitolite list-phy-repos | gitolite access % $GL_USER W any | grep -v DENIED | cut -f1
```

and then for each repo that comes up with, you cd into it and run 'git grep'

The next stage in complexity would be a list of repos you want to search/not search (because you just happen to be the guy who has access to *all* the repos, and that's not really what you want!).  This gets a little harder to design effectively.  It may be easier to mark searchable repos in the conf file itself, using a groupname of some sort.  The grep command could easily check for membership in that special group as an additional constraint.

Sitaram