# git grep by file extensions

Tags: git, grep, file-extension

I know that, if I wanted to grep for a pattern only on files with certain extensions, I could do this:

```
// searches recursively and matches case insensitively in only javascript files
// for "res" from the current directory
grep -iIr --include=*.js res ./
```

I've been trying to search for a way to do this via git grep as well (to take advantage of git grep's speed from the indexes it stores with its tree), but to no avail. I saw [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-grep-while-excluding-files-in-a-blacklist-td7195648.html) that excluding certain file types is not possible.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Yes, for example:

```
git grep res -- '*.js'
```

Comment: One slight modification - if you're not in the root of your repository, `git grep res -- '/*.js'` might be better...

Comment: @twalberg: But the comment suggests that he wants to look from the current directory [down], surely?

Comment: Ah... right... The question didn't specifically say that, but the comment in the code block does.

Comment: I do wish to search from the current directory down.

Comment: Just saw your comment @twalberg. That's exactly what I needed for searching from a given path. :-)

Comment: @Vinay: The simplest way is to `cd` to where you wan to search from and run `git grep` from there. This is the common use case that `git grep` was designed for.

Comment: Just extra information: If you wish to specify a set of file extensions you can use `git grep res -- *.js *.cs` this is covered in another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599474/how-to-git-grep-only-a-set-of-file-extentions)

Comment: what does the `--` accomplish?

Comment: An important thing to not forget is the single quotes around '*.js'. If they are not there, it will not work. (the shell will intercept it before it reaches git).

Comment: git grep res -- '*.proto' gave me what I needed.   Thanks.

Comment: aehlke `--` is a common delimiter in many of git's commands to separate arguments with a set of files to operate on.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
find . -type f -iname '*.js' -exec grep -i 'pattern' {} +
```

Comment: `{}` is the current file and `+` means to treat the maximum arguments at the same time unlike `{} \;` (only one file at a time). Check `man find`

Comment: The question asks for "git" grep.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to search across all branches, you can use the following:

```
git log -Sres --all --name-only -- '*.js'
```

(I see you specify git grep; to me the approach here seems simpler and easier to remember--more like other operations I need commonly.)

Answer (score 0):

### Quick summary

```bash
# Search only in files ending in .h or .c
git grep 'my search' -- '*.[ch]'
```

### Details

`man git grep` shows the following. Check out the description of `<pathspec>`, as well as the several examples here:

```
       <pathspec>...
           If given, limit the search to paths matching at least one pattern.
           Both leading paths match and glob(7) patterns are supported.

           For more details about the <pathspec> syntax, see the pathspec
           entry in gitglossary(7).

EXAMPLES
       git grep 'time_t' -- '*.[ch]'
           Looks for time_t in all tracked .c and .h files in the working
           directory and its subdirectories.

       git grep -e '#define' --and \( -e MAX_PATH -e PATH_MAX \)
           Looks for a line that has #define and either MAX_PATH or PATH_MAX.

       git grep --all-match -e NODE -e Unexpected
           Looks for a line that has NODE or Unexpected in files that have
           lines that match both.

       git grep solution -- :^Documentation
           Looks for solution, excluding files in Documentation.
```

Two really good examples above are:

```bash
# Looks for time_t in all tracked .c and .h files in the working
# directory and its subdirectories.
git grep 'time_t' -- '*.[ch]'

# Looks for solution, excluding files in Documentation.
git grep solution -- :^Documentation
```

Notice the glob `*.[ch]` pattern in the first one to mean "anything.h or anything.c", and the `:^` in the second one to mean "not". So, apparently `:^Documentation` means "not in the `Documentation` file or folder".