# How to git grep only a set of file extensions

Tags: git, grep, file-extension

How do you perform a git grep and limit the files checked to a set of files. I would like to be able to grep the contents of .cpp and .h files looking for MyFunc. eg:

```
git grep "MyFunc" -- *.[hc]*
```

However this also matches, .c files and .cs files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git grep by file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867705/git-grep-by-file-extensions)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use:

```
git grep "MyFunc" -- '*.cpp' '*.h'
```

The quotes are necessary so that git expands the wildcards rather than the shell. If you omit them, it'll only search files in the current directory, rather than including subdirectories.

Comment: It seems the quotes aren't necessary for me... Not using them gets me files from directories deep down as well. Using git bash on win 7

Comment: To recursively search in your repo, call `git grep "MyFunc" -- **/*.cpp`

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved when using git bash in Windows by using:

```
git grep "MyFunc" -- *.{cpp,h}
```

or even simpler:

```
git grep "MyFunc" -- *.cpp *.h
```

The explanation of pathspec on the [git glossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html) mentions that patterns are matched using [fnmatch(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/fnmatch.html). Which matches patterns (including multiple characters) as described by [Shell and Utilities volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Section 2.13.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13_01) and leads to [basic regular expressions matching multiple characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06) and gave me the first solution.

Further research lead me to the second solution by looking into documentation on [glob](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob).

Comment: Warning: both `*.{cpp,h}` and `*.cpp *.h` only search files in the current directory, not in subdirectories, since they are expanded by the shell (not by git). Instead to include subdirectories you should use: `'*.cpp' '*.h'` (in case you're wondering, `'*.{cpp,h}'` doesn't work, as git doesn't understand that syntax).

Comment: Perhaps it depends on your shell / environment. This answer works for me using on Windows with GitBash (msysgit bash shell).

Comment: Even weird in my case, it works for specific file types and not for specific. Or maybe it works some levels deep and that's it (using bash on mac)