# How can I find modified lines that match a certain pattern with Git?

Tags: git, triggers

I wish to write a pre-commit Git trigger that finds unwanted changes. How can I find modified lines about to be committed by Git that match a certain pattern, while obtaining corresponding file name and line number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the "Fun with git grep" article from [Junio C Hamano](https://github.com/gitster) (main maintainer of Git), you can use [`git grep`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep):

```
git grep --cached -n -e 'What You are looking for' -- '*.typeOfFile'
git grep --cached -n -e "What You are looking for" -- '*.typeOfFile'
```

For instance:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\go\src\github.com\VonC\asciidocgo>
git grep --cached -n -e "testa" -- "*.go"
abstractNode.go:3:testa
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ |
  (file name)   --> (line number)
```

---

Note: for existing commits, you could have combined [`git grep`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929502/6309)) and [`git blame`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) functions, as shown in this [blog post](http://ramin.is/blog/2012/04/02/git-grep-and-blame-bash-function/)

```
ggb.sh

# runs git grep on a pattern, and then uses git blame to who did it
ggb() {
    git grep -n $1 | while IFS=: read i j k; do git blame -L $j,$j $i | cat; done
}
```

But in your case, you want to look at the index (about to be committed), not existing commits.

---

Note that "`git grep`" did not quote a path with unusual character like other commands (like "`git diff`", "`git status`") do, but did quote when run from a subdirectory, both of which has been corrected with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), .

See [commit 45115d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45115d84901876b9300c1b6eba333cd8b25b1991) (19 Apr 2020) by [Matheus Tavares (`matheustavares`)](https://github.com/matheustavares).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 33a1060](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33a106098824f50ec0e2e7d642cea26f9a384da4), 28 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`grep`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45115d84901876b9300c1b6eba333cd8b25b1991): follow conventions for printing paths w/ unusual chars
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Greg Hurrell</sup>
>   <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Matheus Tavares</sup>
>
> `grep` does not follow the conventions used by other Git commands when printing paths that contain unusual characters (as double-quotes or newlines).
>   Commands such as `ls-files`, `commit`, `status` and `diff` will:
>
> - Quote and escape unusual pathnames, by default.
> - Print names verbatim and unquoted when "`-z`" is used.
>
> But `grep` *never* quotes/escapes absolute paths with unusual chars and *always* quotes/escapes relative ones, even with "`-z`".
>   Besides being inconsistent in its own output, the deviation from other Git commands can be confusing.
>
> So let's make it follow the two rules above and add some tests for this new behavior. Note that, making grep quote/escape all unusual paths by default, also make it fully compliant with the `core.quotePath` configuration, which is currently ignored for absolute paths.

Comment: Thank you, git grep is a very useful tool which I wasn't aware of.