# Can plain Git search / grep within a Path?

Tags: git, grep

Is there a way, similar to Github's abilities, so search for code in Git history subsetted to within certain folders? 
https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code

Another SO question discussed how to search in general, 
[How to grep (search) committed code in the git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history)

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
git log -p -S <string> -- <path>
```

```
-p                 Generate patch (see section on generating patches).

-S <string>        Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of
                   <string>. Note that this is different than the string simply
                   appearing in diff output.
```

[`git log`](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)