# How to print all TODO comments I ever added or edited during any git commit

Tags: git, git-commit, todo, text-search

How can I list all TODO comments I ever added or edited within all commits of a git versioned project? I do not want to see everyone else's TODO comments.

The output should print all lines actually containing *my* TODO comments:

```
\\TODO: This should be changed to something else
\\TODO I guess the bug hides here
\\ TODO I need to do something here
```

I do not want to just list the commits themselves as `git log -S TODO` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that TODO is in files (as opposed to the commit message), you can do:

```
git log -p --author=you -S TODO | grep "\+.*TODO"
```

See more at "[How to grep (search) committed code in the git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928721/6309)".
`-p`: to see the content as a patch, which allows to grep on the line including the TODO.

However, this lists all `TODO` comments ever written, even those that already resolved and thus removed again from code.

For a more complete answer, see "[How to list all my TODO messages in the current git managed code base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25042219/6309)":

> `git grep -l TODO | xargs -n1 git blame -f -n -w | grep "Your name" | grep TODO | sed "s/.\{9\}//" | sed "s/(.*)[[:space:]]*//"`

Comment: Great, work like a charm. Do you know how I can reduce the TODO comments only to those that *currently exist*? Such as that later on removed TODO comments won't appear?

Comment: @LarsBlumberg Probably by grepping for a '+', like your edit suggests.

Comment: This still prints TODO comments that one added earlier and then removed during later commits. What I would like to see is all my TODO comments in the current base.

Comment: @LarsBlumberg not easy, because the content of a TODO line might have change between its introduction and its removal.

Comment: Ok, maybe I need to use another tool chain than `git log`.

Comment: @LarsBlumberg or at least ask a new question, with a link back to this one for reference.

Comment: Here is it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039242/how-to-list-all-my-todo-messages-in-the-current-git-managed-code-base