# Git: How to list all my TODO messages in the last week?

Tags: git, search, grep

I want to search for lines in my git repository that contain a certain word/phrase by a specific author and have been changed in a specific time/revision range.

For example, I would like to see all the lines (with their file name) containing the word "TODO", which I have added in the last week.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039242), which has only a partial solution; it doesn't handle the time/revision range. Adding a revision range or the `since` option to the `blame` command in that question's answer doesn't yield the result  I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
$ git log -p -S TODO --author="John Doe" --since="1 week ago" |grep TODO
```

This will show all the commits of the last week, authored by *John Doe* and which contain the word *TODO* in the diff.

Comment: It shows the entire content of these commits. That's way too much information. I'm only looking for the TODO lines written one after the other (with no other information in between).

Comment: That'll omit the file name :\