# Case-insensitive git pickaxe search

Tags: git

I'm trying to find all commits where a particular string or arbitrary capitalisation thereof (e.g. `foobar` ,`FooBar`, `fooBar`) was introduced/removed in a git repository.

Based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929502/601626) (which covers a different basic use case), I first tried using `git grep`

```
git rev-list --all | xargs git grep -i foobar
```

This was pretty awful, as it only gave information as to whether the string is present in a commit, so I ended up with loads of superfluous commits.

I then tried `pickaxe`, which got me most of the way there, e.g.

```
git log --pickaxe-regex -S'foobar' --oneline
```

This only got the lowercase `foobar`. I tried the `-i` flag, but that doesn't seem to apply to the `--pickaxe-regex` option. I then resorted to using patterns like this, which got me a bit further:

```
git log --pickaxe-regex -S'.oo.ar' --oneline
```

Is there a way to make `--pickaxe-regex` do case-insensitive matching?

I'm using git v1.7.12.4.

Comment: Just to be sure, try without the single quotes, and try with a more recent Git (preferably 2.0+). But keep in mind `-i` won't work with `'.oo.ar'` (regexp) before Git 2.0.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The way the `-i` is used with pickaxe (see [commit accccde](https://github.com/git/git/commit/accccde483c3cfd55ef55037e8802ca0baaee5a1), git 1.7.10, April 2012) is:

```
git log -S foobar -i --oneline
```

or

```
git log --regexp-ignore-case -Sfoobar
```

or

```
git log -i -Sfoobar
```

Note that with 1.x git versions this option will not work with a regexps, only with a fixed string. It works with regexps only since git 2.0 and [commit 218c45a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/218c45a45c4e1c3b09a1b6b2bc6e6ed457e38a9f), git 2.0, May 2014.

Comment: I'm probably still missing something here. I tried searching for a plain string using --pickaxe-regex, i.e. 'git log --pickaxe-regex -S foobar -i --online', and got 0 results. 'git log -i -S foobar --oneline' got me several hits.

Comment: @Rob you said options 2 and 3 were working. That would be `-Sfoobar`, not `-S foobar`. (no need for `--pickaxe-regex` if you are using the `-S`: I'll fix the answer)