# git search commits for changed string and list files with that string in that commit

Tags: git, search, git-commit

I have managed to find a resource to search for "a" string in all commits (link below).  But I do not know how to do the same command and have the specific files within the commits be listed (which added or lost that string).

All commits would be good but ideally I'd also like to get a list of files that added or lost that string within a **specific** commit.  How would I do this for all or a specific commit?

[Finding a Git commit that introduced a string in any branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816134/finding-a-git-commit-that-introduced-a-string-in-any-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the log of a specific commit with:

```
git log -1 <aSHA1>
```

So add your [pickaxe search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385294/6309) to that:

```
git log --name-only -1 -S "<whatever>" <aSHA1>
```

Comment: both methods only give me the commit sha1, the author, and the date.  No file or line data, sorry.

Comment: @OliverWilliams I have added the --name-only option for listing files (but not lines)

Comment: - however, and this is not the question I've asked, running the command shown on github doesn't seem to remove the sensitive data as I wished: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Comment: @OliverWilliams Indeed: could you ask a new question for that? (I have to go, but I will review it later)