# Git search for string in a files of the certain commit

Tags: git

I have a number of files containing a string `foo`. Also, I added `foo` to the new and old files with a certain commit.

I tried [Case-insensitive git pickaxe search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385294/2109121)

```
git log -S foo -i --oneline
```

but it shows only commit titles.

I tried

```
git diff [commit] [prev_commit] | grep foo
```

but it does not show filenames. I just want to get a list of created or modified files with `foo` string.

Answer (score 2):

You're just short an option, try with `--name-only` and it'll show file names.

Comment: `git log -S foo -i --oneline --name-only` shows all history instead of the only certain commit, but it solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Just limit to one commit and point to the right one (`-1 <commitHash>`) within your log command : `git log -S foo -i --oneline --name-only -1 <commitHash>` or alternatively use `git show`

Answer (score 0):

By default, `git log` does not show the content of the commits, but you were on the good direction:

```
git log -S foo -i --oneline --patch
```

the `--patch` option will show the content of each commit.

EDIT:
Actually it is not quite what you needed, as you did not ask for the commit content, just the filenames. If you don't want the content, @RomainValeri's answer is better.