# GIT search files across projects using regex

Tags: git, git-branch

Hi i would like to search for a file using a particular pattern in my GIT repo that has multiple projects .

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A git repo doesn't know about the notion of "project".

You can simply grep in your current working tree (if those projects are checked out)

Or you can use [`git grep`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) in order to search in the *history* of those same files, across branches.

See "[How to grep (search) committed code in the git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929502/6309)"

Comment: Hi Thanks .. One last thing  . I am not looking at history here . I am looking for count of java files across projects in GIT  . So i will grep "*.java"  .. Will this still work

Comment: How do i grep a file pattern in Stash in an entire repository .. Without checking out the project i.e clone

Comment: @BalajiV you can also search online, but only with the hosting service allows it. For example, if your repo is hosted on GitHub, you can search for a string in java files.