# How to search for a phrase into all git commits ?

Tags: git

I need to search a word in all files of my repository and in all version of all files. This because I don't know when, but there is no more a piece of code in one of my file and I want to know when was deleted and recover it.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this was what you meant, but if you want to find all commits where commit message contains given word, use

```
$ git log --grep=word
```

If you want to find all commits where "word" was added or removed in the file contents (to be more exact: where number of occurences of "word" changed), i.e. search the commit contents, use so called 'pickaxe' search with

```
$ git log -Sword
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try. The second (-S) is my necessity.

Comment: I actually got this off another question on stackoverflow, all I did was search google for "how to grep git commits", or well, "how to search git commits"

Comment: Anyway, I'm glad to help

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do here is grep ([documentation on git-grep](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)) through the history of all revisions in the repository:

```
$ git grep <your_search_term> $(git rev-list --all)
```

Where `<your_search_term>` is a regex pattern.

The output will include all of the commits including your found text/expression.