# git log regex search

Tags: regex, git, bash, git-log

I just found out the differences between 

`git log --all -G "mystring"`

and,

`git log --all -S "mystring"`

as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history/), for example.

But, I'd like to know if I can specify several regular expressions (a.k.a. regex) to `-G`, with something like:

`git log --all -G "str1" --and -G "str2"`

Of course, I can always wrap git commands inside python or bash scripts, but I'd like to know if using pure-git-commands, I can do this.

Thanks very much!!

Comment: Not quite an answer, but: `-S` takes a string while `-G` takes a regex (already), and you can make the `-S` argument a regex by adding `--pickaxe-regex`. See the gitdiffcore documentation: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitdiffcore.html - and then note that "exp1 AND exp2" is almost (but not exactly) "(exp1.*exp2)|(exp2.*exp1)" in "regex algebra".

Answer (score 1):

To search the commit log (across all branches) for the given text:

```
git log --all --grep='String'
```

so

```
git log --grep=str1 --grep=str2
```

will list commits mentioned either str1 or str2 in their commit log messages

Comment: Should also show the `--all-match` option, which ANDs all of the `--grep`s