# Git: How to look for a folder across all versions of a repo?

Tags: git

I have a repository cloned in my PC, and came across a link refering to a folder I couldn't find anywhere. In fact, a link to the code I'm looking for gives 404 as a result. Is there any way to try to find it across all versions/branches?

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you can grep in commit content like explained on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history)

```
git grep "Your Link" $(git rev-list --all)
```

Another solution is to used log command:

```
git log -S"Your Link"
```