# How to find text in the working tree's changed lines?

Tags: git, search

I have some modified files in my repo's working tree, and I want to search for some text in the changed lines of these files. I can only find how to search in the previous commits using `git grep`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `git diff` and then pipe it to `grep`:

```
git diff --unified=0 | grep --ignore-case "text"
```

Setting `--unified=0` makes sure that only the changed lines are returned, without their context.