# Find commit that deleted a line between two revision

Tags: git, diff, blame

I am trying to find the commit that deleted a line between between two revisions. I could not find it directly.

This is what I tried in the following:

```
git blame $v1..$v2 -L $line,+1 --reverse -- $file_name
```

then this command line returns the line that was deleted and not the commit in question. I searching for this character string using these methods:

1- Search in commits that have modified the function where the line is.

```
git show $commit:$file | grep -Fq "$st"
```

2- Searching using the character string.

```
git log $v1...$v2 --pretty=format:"%h"  -S"$String" $file
```

In the first, I could not find the function containing that line (or it doesn't exist) in some cases. In the second approach, The string could be repeated in several cases and I need to review all of them.

I need a better way to find the commit that deleted the line.

Comment: `git log -G` I believe is what you're looking for :)

Comment: But it still the same problem, because the "git log -G" will return the commits that have a modification of a similar string. I could have several commits in return (same string eg("return 0")) ...

Comment: sorry but not helpful, I applied strategies that were sited in most of responses about this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use a [pickaxe search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928721/6309)

```
git log -SFoo -- path_containing_change
```

That lists commits which introduced the string Foo, but also the commits where Foo was *deleted*.
Yes, with that approach you need to review those commits in order to determine which one add or remove `Foo`.

Comment: the problem here, when we have just Foo="return 0", we will have a lot of responses of changes that are not really included in what we are expecting.

Comment: @AmineBarrak Even when limited to a specific file?

Comment: yes, sure in a file there is several "return 0". Let's say in many cases. It is not a concrete solution

Comment: @AmineBarrak And if you limit it to a *function* within a file? Would that work? See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--Lltstartgtltendgtltfilegt

Comment: I did that part already, on the step one of my search of the commit

Comment: @AmineBarrak no, I mean, per function, not per line. And using log, not blame.

Comment: Actualy in the first search part, I determine commits changing the function where the line were modified and search on these commits one by one and find where the string were modified.

Comment: @AmineBarrak That is what git log -S would do, especially when using the function name in -L.