# Searching in removed files with Git

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm trying to find a commit in a legacy app. The commit removes a SOAP service from the codebase. I see a property for the url left unused. There are too many commits and I haven't managed to find any matching by its message (something like "removing..." or "get rid of...").

I would like to find in Git history files containing certain text (in my case it is usage of the property with the url). Is there a way to do it with Git?

Thank you!

**UPDATE** I need not deleted files names but also those deleted files containing  text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grep (search) committed code in the git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`git log` doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--Sltstringgt):

> -S
>
> Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file. Intended for the
>   scripter’s use.
>
> It is useful when you’re looking for an exact block of code (like a struct), and want to know the history of that block since it first
>   came into being: use the feature iteratively to feed the interesting
>   block in the preimage back into -S, and keep going until you get the
>   very first version of the block.

---

```
git log -S "your-url"
```

If you also want the diff

```
git log -S "your-url" -p
```

Comment: that works for me, thanks, man! just add `--diff-filter=D` to the options list