# How to search a Git repository by content (i.e., a regexp in across all previous states of a repo, not just commit messages)

Tags: git, search, commit

That is basically it: I would like to search for a specific expression across all the previous states of my repo.

I have read that one can search all past commits one by one or searching for the commit message, but not for content.

Before using git I had different versions stored in my folder, so I would just need to search  across files an expression that I used in one of my previous versions that I wanted to find again. However, using git I don't know how to go about that.

Comment: So like a repository-wide, recursive text search across all versions of your repo?

Comment: What about the "pickaxe"?

Comment: Yes, recursive text search accross all versions. Wouldn't that be useful? What is pickaxe?

Comment: No comments? I´m surprised this feature is not implemented yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to grep (search) committed code in the Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history)

Comment: solution found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929502/8667766