# find when a specific word get merge into a git branch in a specific file

Tags: git, github, version-control

Greeting Dear community.

How we can find the time point and commit label of a specific word/change being merged into a file in a branch in Git.

Example: we know the word <is_pending_to_pay> is the new word/change and we want to find
when it is being merged into the branch

We have 2 branches off the master. Branch_1 and Branch_2

We can find when that change/word is being introduced into Branch_2

However, that change/word is NOT suppose to be in Branch_1 but it does.

We try to find when it happens of the merge history of Branch_1 but no luck.

So we go to Branch_2 again with that commit label when that word/change is being merge but
we cant find the same label??

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the [pickaxe option of `git log`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928721/6309)

```
git checkout Branch1
git log -Sis_pending_to_pay --first-parent
```

You will see the first commit where `is_pending_to_pay` was introduced.