# how to find commits in a given file containing a specific text?

Tags: git

There is a file in my git repo which was changed a lot of times. I want to know the revisions in which a specific text was present in this file.

Is there a git command to get this information?

Something like:

```
git find "specific_text" -- /frequently/modified/file
```

Which would output a list of commits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to grep (search) committed code in the Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history)

Comment: It is not called `find`, it is called `grep`. Type `git help grep` in your terminal or read its [documentation on the Git website](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`git grep <pattern>` will search *only one commit*.

If you want to search *all of git's history*, use one of the pickaxe options :

```
git log -G "specific_text" -- frequently/modified/file
# or :
git log -S "specific_text" -- frequently/modified/file
```

The difference between the two is [explained in the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt) :

- `-G` will list all commits where `specific_text` appears in the diff,
- `-S` will only list commits where the count of `specific_text` changes, e.g : the commit where this text appears, the commit where it gets deleted, but not a commit which just moves it around, without adding or removing an instance.

---

You can also add `-p` if you want to see the diff itself :

```
git log -p -S "specific_text" -- frequently/modified/file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```sh
git log -G 'specific text' --  /frequently/modified/file
```