# Better way to search git history

Tags: git

I quite frequently do `git log -p` looking for a line of code change, usually a removal. This opens less, and then I do a /search for what I'm looking for. This does work. However once I've found it I sometimes want to see the commit log for this file, usually to determine when. This usually involves a lot of scrolling due to many file commits. Is there a  good way to stop scrolling, and just jump directly to the commit?

Comment: why not using one of many graphical front-ends? My favorites: `git extenstions` (windows only), `SourceTree` (sucks on Windows), `GitKraken`.

Comment: @MarekR in my current working environment I am not allowed to install unapproved software. I am looking for a new job. I don't know if I can use source tree, etc.

Comment: How about `gitk`? it is usually shipped with `git` as default graphical front-end, so you may already have it. Its ugly and a bit strange UI flow, but it is turbo fast.

Comment: @MarekR yeah probably. I'm just a terminal monkey

Comment: I love `ungit`. It's a lovely way to visualise git commit trees.

Answer (score 1):

To find which file the hit's in is just `?^diff`; then the search string to find the commit header is `?^commit` , with that trailing space, if you're using the default header format, or `?^[a-f0-9]{5}` if you're using `--oneline`

Apparently mercurial has a diff scraper that condenses the hits and metadata to one line each, [I wrote an equivalent as a simple lex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65204346/1290731) for fun.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for commit which removed specific line there is better way to do it.

Using `git log`:

```sh
git log -S <string which was added/removed> path/to/file
```

Using `git blame`:

```sh
git blame --reverse START..END filename
```

Comment: Also: `git log -G`. While `-S` and `-G` differ in several ways (in particular one defaults to simple string and one to regular expression), the *big* difference is that `-G` looks at the diff to see if it *contains* something, while `-S` looks at the diff to see if the *number of somethings changes*. For instance, suppose we have diff that changes the spelling of a word *W* that comes before a second word *X* that's either added or removed. `git log -S X` will find the diff because it adds/removes X. `git log -G X` will find the diff too. But `git log -S W` won't, while `git log -G W` will.