# Edit a commit message from a merged branch

Tags: git

I have a `dev` branch in which I have merged a `feature` branch.

```
-A------B----C-G-H-I-> dev
        /
-D--E--F  feature
```

After the merge, I made multiple other commits (G,H,I).
Is it possible to edit the commit message of D and E :

- Without having to re-merge manually
- Without losing C,G,H and I

I tried using `git rebase -i -r HEAD~6` (because I want to edit E, which is the 6th commit), but git still prompts me to the manual merging of `feature` into `dev` (which essentially have already made through B).

Can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment : it is not possible to do it without a manual intervention.

`git rebase -r` does not spot the following situation :

- I am about to replay a merge between commits `A'` and `F'`,
- they have the exact same contents as the original commits `A` and `F`,
- so I'm going to use the exact same content as the original merge commit `B` for the result.

---

However, if you *know* that you only reworded the message and didn't change the *content* of the commits, it is easy to "use the content of `B`" manually :

when `git rebase` stops on the merge step :

- restore the content of the original commit `B` :

  ```
  git restore -s B -SW . # short flags for:
                         # git restore --source B --staged --worktree .
  # or
  git checkout B -- .
  ```
- then proceed with the rebase :

  ```
  git rebase --continue
  ```

Comment: Although I'm really into long answers, just for the sake of completeness, I feel like this one is more straight to the point.

Answer (score 0):

First: no part of any existing commit can ever be changed.  That means you cannot touch any of the saved snapshot, nor any of the commit metadata (name, email address, date-and-time stamps, log message, parent commit hash ID, and so on).

All operations that *seem* to change a commit—including both `git commit --amend` and `git rebase -i`—actually work by making *new and different (presumably improved) commits*.  You must then convince everyone who *was* using the *old* commits to drop those in favor of the new commits.

This is easy to do if you're the only one with those commits: you need only convince yourself that your new and improved commits are the ones to use, and you get that for free by making the new and improved commits.

It's harder to do when you have given the old commits to someone else, via `git push` for instance.  You now not only have to convince yourself—which is easy and free since Git just does it as you use the commands that do it—but also convince *everyone else*.  That usually involves using `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease`, and then often requires something else beyond that as well.  But if the other Git repository belongs *to* you (e.g., on GitHub) and nobody else has picked up those new commits, the force-push operation alone will suffice and you'll be OK there.

With all that in mind, you *can* potentially use `git rebase -i -r` here.  But it won't do what you've *asked for*, it will at best do what you *want* instead.  A better plan may be to use `git replace` and `git filter-branch` or `git filter-repo` (though these are tricky), or just to do this manually (less tricky, but a little bit cumbersome—but not as much as you might think).

#### Background

A regular rebase—interactive or not—that *doesn't* involve any merges works by copying the old commits to new-and-improved ones.  For instance, if you had:

```
...--A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

with a typo in the commit message for `B`.  Then `HEAD~6` works well because we count back six times from `G`: `F`, `E`, `D`, `C`, `B`, `A`.  This is both the target commit—the new and improved replacements will go here—and the first commit *not* to copy, so that the set of commits to copy are `B-C-D-E-F-G`.  Using interactive rebase, you then change the `pick` directive for commit `B` to `edit`, so that Git copies the commit's effect but gives you a chance to update or replace the commit *message* before making the new-and-improved commit.  When Git makes the new and improved `B'` commit, you have, at this point in the middle of the rebase, something that looks like this:

```
       B'   <-- HEAD
      /
...--A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- dev
```

The rebase operation then goes on to copy `C` to `C'`, `D` to `D'`, and so on.  The end result, just before yanking the name `dev` over, is:

```
       B'-C'-D'-E'-F'-G'   <-- HEAD
      /
...--A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- dev
```

As its final step, `git rebase` grabs the original branch name, forces it to point to the last-copied commit `G'`, and re-attaches `HEAD`:

```
       B'-C'-D'-E'-F'-G'   <-- dev (HEAD)
      /
...--A--B--C--D--E--F--G   [abandoned]
```

The original commits can't be found easily any more, since there is no *name* for the last one.  So they seem to be gone, and it *seems* that we somehow magically changed the commits.  We didn't: the old commits are still there, still under their original hash IDs.  The new commits have new, different hash IDs.  Changing the contents of the commit *message* for `B` resulted in a new and different hash ID for the new and improved `B'`, and we then had to copy `C` to a new and improved `C'` whose only *real* change is that it links backwards to `B'` instead of `B`.  This necessitated the copying of `D` to `D'` so that `D'` can point to `C'`, and so on down the line.

#### Your case

With your more complex graph:

```
...--A-------B--C--G--H--I   <-- dev
            /
...--D--E--F   <-- feature
```

you have a different problem: you want to copy `D` and `E` to new-and-improved commits, `D'` and `E'`.  This will force you to copy `F` to a new and improved `F'`, so that the name `feature` can locate commit `F'`.  You now have to do a new `git merge` to merge `F'` with `A`; the result of this new merge will be a copy of `B`, `B'`, with one of the parents still being `A` but the other parent being `F'` instead of `F`.

Having copied `B` to `B'`, you are now in the same situation we had with a standard rebase: we have to copy all subsequent commits to new-and-improved commits, where the only actual "improvement" is that the linkages back to their parents go to the new-and-improved commits.  That is, the "improvement" has to bubble all the way down to the end of the line, just as before.  So we won't *lose* the `C-G-H-I` sequence, but we have to *re-copy* these.  Any old `git rebase` can do that, because that part is linear.

That gives us the direct answer to the question you asked, as you asked it:

> ...  Is it possible to edit the commit message of D and E:
>
> - Without having to re-merge manually
> - Without losing C,G,H and I

We definitely have to re-merge.  How *manual* this has to be is another question, but `git rebase -r` has some issues here: rebase needs to know *which commits to copy*, and there's no good and simple way to tell it to copy `B` by redoing the merge, and to copy `D` and `E` and `F` and `C` through `I`, but not other commits.  In particular `HEAD~6` means *count back six **first** parents*.<sup>1</sup>  You say (slightly paraphrasing) that you

> merged `feature` into `dev`

by which I take it you ran `git checkout dev` and then `git merge feature` or equivalent.  This means that the *first* parent of merge `B` is commit `A`, so you'd want `git rebase -r -i HEAD~5` to exclude commit `A` while keeping commit `B`.  This would include commits `D-E-F` in the list of commits to copy, but might also include many earlier commits, and perhaps many earlier merges as well.

There's no way for Git to *copy* a merge commit in general.  So with `-r`, `git rebase` just *re-runs* the merge.  Any conflicts you resolved earlier will recur.  In this one specific case, there is a way to copy the merge, but Git doesn't use it.  That gives us a bunch of options:

- Re-perform the merge, re-resolving any conflicts.  That's the direct way.  You probably don't want to do this though!  (Especially if there were some tough conflicts.)
- Turn on `git rerere`.  This has Git save the conflict resolutions, so that Git can do its own re-resolving.  This has one problem: it has to have been turned on *at the time you resolved the conflicts*, so if it wasn't, you need to go back in time<sup>2</sup> and turn it on.  Actually there's a script to get Git to "re-learn" the conflict resolution (`git rerere-train`; see also [What is git-rerere and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49500943/1256452)).  It's still a bit of a pain though.
- Go ahead and use manual re-merging.  This is easier than it sounds!
- Use `git replace` and filter-branch / filter-repo.  This is harder than it sounds, unfortunately, and I won't even go into any details here.

---

<sup>1</sup>The *first parent* thing is irrelevant in a linear chain, because here, every parent is a first-parent:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-...
```

Commit `H` has one parent `G`, so its first parent is `G`, its last parent is `G`, and its only parent is `G`: there's only one parent!  What *first parent* means only really comes into effect when we hit a merge:

```
       I--J
      /    \₁
...--H      M--N   <-- branch
      \    /²
       K--L
```

Commit `N` has one parent `M`, but commit `M` has two parents: `J` and `L`.  One of these is the *first parent*.  Here I've annotated the arrows so that we can see parent #1 goes to `J`.  The other parent is therefore the second parent.  Git has a flag, `--first-parent`, meaning *follow only first parent links*, and has that syntax, `~6` as a suffix for instance, which also means *follow only the first parent links*.  Following the second parent is harder: we can write branch~1^2 to reach commit `L`, where `branch~1` means *step back one first parent* from `N` to `M`, and then `^2` means *step back to the second parent*.  Or, `branch^1^2` also gets us to `L`: `branch^1` means *first parent of `N`* which is `M`; `^2` then means *second parent* as before.  Leaving out the number means "1", so `branch^^2` or `branch~^2` are also ways to get to commit `L`.  Using `branch^^2^` gets us to commit `K`, and `branch^^2^^` or `branch^^2~2` gets us to commit `H`.  The syntax `branch~4` is an easier way to name commit `H`: we count back four first-parent links, going from `N` to `M` (1 link) to `J` (2 links) to `I` (3 links) to `H` (4 links).

<sup>2</sup>Got a spare DeLorean or TARDIS?

---

#### Manual re-merging is probably the right answer

To make your job easy, or at least easy-ish:

1. `git checkout feature` or `git switch feature` so that you're using commit `F` via the branch name.
2. Use `git rebase -i` to rewrite commits `D-E-F`.  The branch name `feature` will now point to the updated `F'`.
3. Use `git checkout` with the historic commit hash ID of commit `A` (find it with `git log` if needed).  This gives you a detached HEAD, so if you prefer `git switch`, use `git switch --detach` (the `git switch` command requires this flag to produce a detached HEAD state).
4. Run `git merge feature` or `git merge -n feature`.  This will attempt a merge of `A` and the updated `F'`.  If it works all the way through, producing a merge—it won't if you use `-n`—you will get:

   ```
   ...--D'-E'-F'   <-- feature
               \
                B'  <-- HEAD
          _____/
         /
   ...--A-------B--C--G--H--I   <-- dev
               /
   ...--D--E--F
   ```

   If you encounter merge conflicts, or use `-n`, the merge will stop before making commit `B'`.  Now you have a chance to *completely replace the merge result* if you like, by reading into Git's index from commit `B`:
5. Run `git read-tree --reset -u <hash-of-B>` if desired: this erases the entire merge-result-so-far and brings in the files from commit `B`.  Then run `git commit`.  Or, if you didn't use `-n` and the merge worked on its own the first time, the merge in step 3 will already have worked on its own this second time, and you'll already have commit `B'`.  You can, if you like, run `git diff` to compare the new commit `B'` against the original commit `B`: the two *trees* should have the *same content*, so this diff should be entirely empty.
6. Run `git cherry-pick dev~4..dev`.  This will copy commits `C-G-H-I`, the same way rebase does.  Modern cherry-pick understands the two-dot syntax here (in fact this has been in Git for many years now, though modern cherry-pick is smarter than the versions that this first went into: the same code base now implements `git rebase -i` now, so you're actually using the same code *as* rebase).
7. Verify that you like the result of all of this.  If so, force the name `dev` to point to the current commit:

   ```
   git branch -f dev HEAD
   ```

   or:

   ```
   git checkout -B dev
   ```

Comment: what happened to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67376514/86072 ? ;)

Comment: @LeGEC: [I need a lot more time to write a short answer.](https://lettersrepublic.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/defragging-a-scene-and-killing-an-internet-lie/) :-)

Comment: [better link](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/04/28/shorter-letter/) (that took too long to find)