# How to tell if a string ever existed in my repo using SourceGraph?

Tags: sourcegraph

I want to see if a string ever existed in my repo (deleted file, changed file, etc). In git, I think it would like this `- git grep <regexp> $(git rev-list --all)`. This is based on this post [How to grep (search) committed code in the Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history)

Can I do such a search in sourcegraph? If so, what's the syntax

This is what I have so far:

```
repo:^<url to my repo>$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this part of the [documentation](https://docs.sourcegraph.com/code_search/reference/queries#repository-revisions) addresses it directly. I just missed it.

You use a glob pattern to search over the repos.

```
@*refs/heads/* - search across all branches
```