# git v2.10.0.win => concatenate all versions of a file into one big file

Tags: git

Hello is there a way with git command line to print all versions of a file into a big concatenated file.

It would also be ok that only the diffs are printed.

I want to search for a pattern in ALL commit versions  of a certain file and I dont want to manually look into every commit version.

Comment: Do you need to concatenate all versions into a file or to [search for a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history)?

Comment: Alvaro is right, you don't have to do this, git allows searching in all history (of all files, or one file).