# Is there a way to search on Github for code that has been changed in commits?

Tags: git, github

For example, let's say I have a variable "UserFavoriteFood" in a repository and a collaborator committed code that changes the value somewhere and I wasn't aware of it. I want to be able to search commits in the repo to find the ones that have "UserFavoriteFood" in it, ordered by recency. The main use case for this is debugging in a large repo.

Comment: Does it have to be in GitHub, or would a local Git solution work?

Comment: Preferably in GitHub, though either works.

Comment: For Git, it's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2928584/3266847), and for GitHub, I don't think there's a built-in way.

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub specifically, there's an API to search commits in the default branch: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#search-commits