# What is the bash reverse quote equivalent in powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell

**Note**: as pasted in the comment, it is called backtick for the symbol ``, and there's already an answer in:
[What's the cmd/PowerShell equivalent of back tick on Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434038/whats-the-cmd-powershell-equivalent-of-back-tick-on-bash)

---

Original question:

In bash, people may use reverse quote(``) as result for quoted commands, and integrated in another command.

For example:

```sh
cmake -DVAR1=VALUE1 `cat ../custom-options.txt`
```

where `../custom_options.txt` contains many lines like:

```
-DBUILD_ZLIB=OFF
-DBUILD_TIFF=OFF
-DBUILD_OPENJPEG=OFF
-DBUILD_JASPER=OFF
-DBUILD_JPEG=OFF
-DBUILD_PNG=OFF
-DBUILD_OPENEXR=OFF
-DBUILD_WEBP=OFF
-DBUILD_TBB=OFF
-DBUILD_IPP_IW=OFF
-DBUILD_ITT=OFF
-DWITH_AVFOUNDATION=OFF
```

For Windows system, it is powershell instead of bash in Linux.
My question: what is the equivalent of reverse quote in PowerShell?

Comment: I think you may be thinking about a script block `{}`

Comment: FYI, you should use `$(  )` instead of the reverse quotes.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: It's called a backtick instead of "reverse quote". In powershell you do the same as in bash: `$()`, or maybe even as a plain `()` outside of double quotes

Comment: @phuclv Thank you, I didn't know it is called backtick until you mentioned it. The pasted link answers my question.