# Programmatically stopping a docker container

Tags: bash, docker

I want to programmatically fetch the id of a running container and stop it. However, I'm a little lost

Here's the command I use to fetch the id of the running container:

```
docker ps -q --no-trunc --format="{{.ID}}" --filter "ancestor=<repo-name>"
```

How do I pass the output of this command to

```
docker stop <id>
```

I'm new to docker, thus the question. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bash, you can use back ticks to evaluate a command and substitute in the command output, in your case:

```sh
docker stop `docker ps -q --no-trunc --format="{{.ID}}" --filter "ancestor=<repo-name>"`
```

Please, consider read [this related Unix Stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4782/how-to-pass-the-output-of-one-command-as-the-command-line-argument-to-another), it may be of help as well.

As suggested in the linked question, you can use the [`$(...)` syntax](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) as well:

```sh
docker stop $(docker ps -q --no-trunc --format="{{.ID}}" --filter "ancestor=<repo-name>")
```

Although I don't know in this specific use case, the `$(...)` syntax has the further advantage of [working with PowerShell too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434038/whats-the-cmd-powershell-equivalent-of-back-tick-on-bash).